# How to change the value of istio.alpn_override to false?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I have an application deployed on Anthos Service Mesh having an ingress gateway. When accessing the application from internet using the external IP address of the ingress gateway I'm facing SSL Handshake-connection reset error. So, as a way forward I need to change the "istio.alpn_override: false" at the gateway level. I'm not able to see in which file & which location did this flag need to be set. Also, could you please let me know if the flag can be overwritten using istioctl commands.

Thanks & Regards,
Kareti Bhavana.